# react-native 0.47 navigator is deprecated but I don't use it

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, babeljs

I know the Navigator is deprecated since 0.44. I'm having this strange red warning when I launch my app even though I don't use this component. I think maybe it is used in one of the modules I've included in my app. I only have add [this one](https://github.com/blackuy/react-native-twilio-video-webrtc) and I didn't find any usage of the Navigator. I really don't know where it's coming from.

I'm using React Native 0.47.1 and React 16.0.0-alpha.12

This is my package.json :

```
{

    "name": "MyProject",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
        "react-native": "0.47.1",
        "react-native-twilio-video-webrtc": "https://github.com/blackuy/react-native-twilio-video-webrtc"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
        "babel-preset-react-native": "2.1.0",
        "jest": "20.0.4",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native"
    }
}
```

[image: rn warning]

Comment: Add your `package.json` as this is an error that could be hard to track down as seen [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14491) and [here](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/1328). Also, can you reproduce this in a brand new project using the same `package.json`?

Comment: Please install node module dependency
npm install react-native-deprecated-custom-components

Comment: @MichaelCheng question edited with package.json

Comment: @NakulKundaliya this is not the matter here since I'm not the one who uses Navigator in my code

Comment: To be sure, just remove **react-native-twilio-video-webrtc** dependency from your project and do an npm install. And check if you still get that warning.

Comment: Doesn't get the warning, so I assume this is coming from the module. However, I can't seem to find any usage of Navigator in it. I'll contact the authors so I can have a clear view on it. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

This could be caused by an incorrect import statement

```
import * as Something from "react-native";
```

I had the same problem. I added an `Alert.alert(...)` statement, and Webstorm proposed to add the `import * as Alert from "react-native";` import.

Replacing this by `import { Alert } from 'react-native'` solved this for me.